# Accessing directory property in Custom Action Wix

Tags: wix

I have a WIX installation I am attempting to run, which has a custom action which creates some .INI files based on user input, and is supposed to put them in a subfolder of the user's chosen installation folder. I am attempting to pass the WIXUI_INSTALLDIR property to the C# Custom Action file, but this just passes its value of INSTALLFOLDER, instead of INSTALLFOLDER's Path. Does anyone have advice on how to do this?

Comment: Why are you attempting to pass WIXUI_INSTALLDIR to custom action? YOu should be passing INSTALLDIR/INSTALLFOLDER

Comment: I am new to WIX and- for some reason- was under the impression that only a Property's value could be accessed by a custom action. Using INSTALLFOLDER resolved that issue quite nicely. Thank you!